# Unity: How to destroy "out of bounds" gameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to destroy the 'enemy' gameObjects when they reach at certain distance on the Z axis. It was working at one point, but... idk. Please let me know if more info is needed.

P.S. I'm currently enrolled in the "Unity: Junior Programmer's Pathway", this is Lab 4.

--- Spawn Manager ---
`
using System.Collections; using System.Collections.Generic; using UnityEngine;

```
public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour { public GameObject enemyPrefab;

private float boundsZ = 5f;
private float boundsX = 14.5f;

private float spawnPosZ = 6.0f;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("GenerateSpawnPosition", 2f, 1.5f);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    Debug.Log(enemyPrefab.transform.position.z);

    // DestroyOutOfBounds
    if (enemyPrefab.transform.position.z < -5)
    {
       Destroy(enemyPrefab.gameObject);
    }
}

// Generate Random Spawn Position
void GenerateSpawnPosition()
{
    float posX = 12.5f;
    float posZ = 6f;
    float randNumX = Random.Range(-posX, posX);
    Vector3 randPos = new Vector3(randNumX, .5f, posZ);

    Instantiate(enemyPrefab, randPos, enemyPrefab.transform.rotation);
}

}`
```

The "Enemy" spawn is set randomly along the X axis. When I log the enemy gameObject's "Z" position it reads "1.93" but programmatically it's set to 6. I tried resetting the "EnemyPrefab" position, as well as, creating a new prefab.

Comment: Presumably something is moving the enemy on the Z axis? Whether it's at Z position 6 or 1.93, it won't be destroyed since it's set to be destroyed only if less than -5.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I've been coding for too long. :facepalm:
Originally I was trying to destroy the enemy gameObject in "SpawnManager.cs", when I should have done so in "Enemy.cs".

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 15.0f;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Enemy Movement
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.back * speed * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.Impulse);

        // Destroy Enemy
        if (transform.position.z < -6)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```